# Debugging the minlength validation jquery program

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a jquery program for validating minlength but it is not working.

I dont know how to solve that 'select_this' problem in there.

I am a beginner in jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="text"]').on('focus',function(){
  var select_this = $(this);
  minlength = select_this.attr('mLength');
  if(minlength != 0 && minlength > 0 && select_this.val().length < minlength ){
   select_this.after('<span>'+ minlength +' characters are required. </span>');
  }
 }).keyup(function(){
  if(select_this.val().length >= minlength ){
   select_this.next().remove();
  }
 }).blur(function(){
  select_this.next().remove();
 });
});
```

```html
     <p>
      5<input type="text" mLength="5" />
  </p>
  <p>
      10<input type="text" mLength="10" />
  </p>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the scope of your variable

```
var select_this = $(this);
```

inside the focus event handler is available inside that handler function only, if you need to access it in other events handler functions  then declare it there as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="text"]').on('focus',function(){
  var select_this = $(this);
  minlength = select_this.attr('mLength');
  if(minlength != 0 && minlength > 0 && select_this.val().length < minlength ){
   select_this.after('<span>'+ minlength +' characters are required. </span>');
  }
 }).keyup(function(){
        var select_this = $(this);
  minlength = select_this.attr('mLength');
  if(select_this.val().length >= minlength ){
   select_this.next().remove();
  }
 }).blur(function(){
        var select_this = $(this);
  select_this.next().remove();
 });
});
```

```html
<p>
      5<input type="text" mLength="5" />
  </p>
  <p>
      10<input type="text" mLength="10" />
  </p>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```